# Showing that $\int_0^{\infty}f_n(x)e^{-x}dx \rightarrow \int_0^{\infty} f(x)e^{-x}dx \quad n \rightarrow \infty$ for a sequence $f_n$ of functions

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n : [0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of bounded functions, which uniformly converge to $f: [0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  Also assume $f_n|[a,b]$ is Riemann-Integrable $\in R([a,b])$ und $\int_0^{\infty} f_n(x)dx$ exists.

Now it has to be shown whether $\int_0^{\infty}f_n(x)e^{-x}dx \rightarrow \int_0^{\infty} f(x)e^{-x}dx \quad n \rightarrow \infty$ holds or not.

I was already able to show that $\int_0^{\infty}f_n(x)dx \rightarrow \int_0^{\infty} f(x)dx \quad n \rightarrow \infty$ does not hold in general.

But I have the feeling it is different if we include $e^{-x}$ into our function. Because $f_n$ is bounded, we can find $x_0$ such that $f_n \leq e^{x_0}$ and therefore $f_ne^{-x} \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.  I have tried to consider $\int_0^{x_0}f_n(x)e^{-x}dx  + \int_{x_0}^{\infty}f_n(x)e^{-x}dx$ but got stuck and also considered $\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x} (f_n(x)-f(x)) dx$ and could not proceed. I would value any input.

Comment: Either you can use Lebesgue theorem, or you will have to cut your integral into two pieces as you did : the bounded part converges to $0$ because of uniform convergence, for the other part, bound it by convergence of integrals.

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/793754/let-f-n-n-in-mathbbn-rightarrow-f-on-0-infty-true-or-false-lim?rq=1

Comment: Consider:  $$|\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x} (f_n(x)-f(x)) dx| \le \int_0^{\infty}e^{-x} |f_n(x)-f(x)| dx$$ $$ \le \sup_{[0,\infty)} |f_n-f| \int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}\, dx = \sup_{[0,\infty)} |f_n-f| \cdot 1.$$

Comment: @zhw. Interestingly, you never used the boundedness of $f_n$.

Comment: True, I just started where the OP left off at the end.